# ValueError: Input shapes do not overlap raster. Geopandas/Rasterio, possible CRS error when masking

Tags: python, gis, mask, geopandas, rasterio

I'm using this dataset:
https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/gpw-v4-population-density-rev11/data-download
(Gridded population density of the world)

With this map:
https://data.humdata.org/dataset/uganda-administrative-boundaries-as-of-17-08-2018
(Uganda administrative boundaries shapefile)

I have clipped the uganda map to the region I need, like so:

```
shape_records = uganda.shapeRecords()
desired_shapes = []

for s in shape_records:
    for x in s.record:
        if 'FORT PORTAL' in str(x):
            desired_shapes.append(s)
```

Loaded them into a single geopandas dataframe:

```
forgpd=[]
for x in desired_shapes:
    forgpd.append(x.__geo_interface__)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(forgpd, crs=4326)
```

Then I'm reading the `.tif` world population file with `rasterio`.

```
gpw = rio.open('UgandaData/gpw_v4_population_density_rev11_2020_30_sec.tif')
gpw_region = gpw.read(1, window=gpw.window(*box))
```

And I'd like to crop it, using this:

```
from rasterio import mask as msk

region_mask, region_mask_tf = msk.mask(dataset=gpw, shapes=gdf.geometry, all_touched=True, filled=True, crop=True) #error here
region_mask = np.where(region_mask < 0, 0, region_mask).squeeze()
```

I get the following errors:

```
WindowError: windows do not intersect
ValueError: Input shapes do not overlap raster.
```

This is my crs:

```
Gridded population of world: CRS.from_epsg(4326)

Uganda(Fort Portal) : 
<Geographic 2D CRS: EPSG:4326>
Name: WGS 84
Axis Info [ellipsoidal]:
- Lat[north]: Geodetic latitude (degree)
- Lon[east]: Geodetic longitude (degree)
Area of Use:
- name: World
- bounds: (-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)
Datum: World Geodetic System 1984
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

Could the difference be that I have not specified WGS 84 for the gridded world population? If so, how is this specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the shapefile is in UTM coordinates and the raster is a world coordinate system (lat/long). Even though you assign the `epsg:4326` crs to `gdf` it's coordinates are still in UTM. You can convert these manually doing something like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351846/using-geopandas-to-convert-linestring-utm-data-to-latlong).

Otherwise, you can re-projected the world raster into `EPSG:21096` (estimation based off UTM zone from the uganda shapefile) using QGIS or you can use [gdalwarp](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html).

After changing the projection on the raster the rest of your code worked.